# How to compress an image from an URL?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, browser

I'm currently developing a website in React for a company which should work as a drive repository in which they will upload files.
I'm having performance issue in the "photos" folder since they are uploading a lot of high res picture and the website is currently showing preview of them.
I guess the smarter solution would be adding a some sort of image compression when they are uploading and saving the low res image to show as a preview but maybe there's a way given a url to an image to get a low resolution version of it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use npmjs.com/package/base64-img npm module. It will convert your images into Bas64. You can use various configurations. Also try to use lazy loading through imageSectionObserver API provided by browsers.

Comment: Base64 is a means of expressing binary data as plain text, a consequence of this is that it takes **more** bytes to convey the same data. That's the opposite of what the OP is asking for.

Comment: You can convert your image as binary and add in your html page. It will add performance. However it depens onthe use case. We can use data-uri.  A data URI is a base64 encoded string that represents a file. Getting the contents of a file as a string means that you can directly embed the data within your HTML or CSS code. When the browser encounters a data URI in your code, it's able to decode the data and construct the original file.

Comment: https://images.guide/ is the best resource for all sort of image optimization technique. For thumbnails , use any serverside to generate a thumbnail while uploading.